# reCAPTCHA not visible in a Aspx page

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for a web application in Asp.net Webform and framework 4.5.
Using the Nuget RecaptchaNet package I inserted a simple reCAPTCHA control into a Webform page.
In the code of the page I inserted, at the top:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Recaptcha.Web" Namespace="Recaptcha.Web.UI.Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

In the page:

```
<cc1:Recaptcha ID="Recaptcha1" PublicKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" PrivateKey="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" runat="server" />
```

But when I run I don't see the reCAPTCHA control and I can't understand why, I searched on Google but didn't find anything useful. Where am I doing wrong?
Another way of using Google's reCAPTCHA would also suit me, but the ones I've tried aren't good for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version, v1 (deprecated), vs or v3? Can you show us the relevant code and markup? Have you used the browser tools and inspected the generated markup?

Comment: Using V2, now check the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself: I had to enter localhost in the Google settings

Comment: Not possible, you don't know? "You can accept your own answer in 7 hours"